# Illegal instruction (core dumped) on 'import torch' - Vega 64, Ubuntu 22.04, ROCm 5.7

Tags: docker, pytorch, amd-rocm

I installed PyTorch in the following steps:

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04
2. Installing PyTorch using Docker Image with PyTorch Pre-Installed from https://rocm.docs.amd.com/en/docs-5.0.2/how_to/pytorch_install/pytorch_install.html#references

2.1 Pull the latest public PyTorch Docker image.

```
~$ docker pull rocm/pytorch:latest
```

2.2 Start a Docker container using the downloaded image.

```
~$ docker run -it --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --device=/dev/kfd --device=/dev/dri --group-add video --ipc=host --shm-size 8G rocm/pytorch:latest
```

Run

```
~$ python3 -c 'import torch' 2> /dev/null && echo 'Success' || echo 'Failure'
```

and got error: **illegal instruction (core dumped)**

Test GPU for rocm

`~$ rocminfo`

```
ROCk module is loaded

HSA System Attributes    

Runtime Version:         1.1
System Timestamp Freq.:  1000.000000MHz
Sig. Max Wait Duration:  18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) (timestamp count)
Machine Model:           LARGE                              
System Endianness:       LITTLE                             
Mwaitx:                  DISABLED
DMAbuf Support:          NO

               
HSA Agents               
              
*******                  
Agent 1                  
*******                  
  Name:                    Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8300  @ 2.50GHz
  Uuid:                    CPU-XX                             
  Marketing Name:          Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8300  @ 2.50GHz
  Vendor Name:             CPU                                
  Feature:                 None specified                     
  Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        0(0x0)                             
  Queue Min Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Max Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    0                                  
  Device Type:             CPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      32768(0x8000) KB                   
  Chip ID:                 0(0x0)                             
  ASIC Revision:           0(0x0)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   2499                               
  BDFID:                   0                                  
  Internal Node ID:        0                                  
  Compute Unit:            4                                  
  SIMDs per CU:            0                                  
  Shader Engines:          0                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   0                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:1                                  
  Features:                None
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: FINE GRAINED        
      Size:                    3965668(0x3c82e4) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: KERNARG, FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    3965668(0x3c82e4) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
    Pool 3                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    3965668(0x3c82e4) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       TRUE                               
  ISA Info:                
*******                  
Agent 2                  
*******                  
  Name:                    gfx900                             
  Uuid:                    GPU-021505f47f984144               
  Marketing Name:          Radeon RX Vega                     
  Vendor Name:             AMD                                
  Feature:                 KERNEL_DISPATCH                    
  Profile:                 BASE_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        128(0x80)                          
  Queue Min Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Queue Max Size:          131072(0x20000)                    
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    1                                  
  Device Type:             GPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      16(0x10) KB                        
    L2:                      4096(0x1000) KB                    
  Chip ID:                 26751(0x687f)                      
  ASIC Revision:           1(0x1)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   1750                               
  BDFID:                   768                                
  Internal Node ID:        1                                  
  Compute Unit:            64                                 
  SIMDs per CU:            4                                  
  Shader Engines:          4                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   1                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:4                                  
  Features:                KERNEL_DISPATCH 
  Fast F16 Operation:      TRUE                               
  Wavefront Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
  Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        1024(0x400)                        
    y                        1024(0x400)                        
    z                        1024(0x400)                        
  Max Waves Per CU:        40(0x28)                           
  Max Work-item Per CU:    2560(0xa00)                        
  Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Grid Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Max fbarriers/Workgrp:   32                                 
  Packet Processor uCode:: 464                                
  SDMA engine uCode::      434                                
  IOMMU Support::          None                               
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    8372224(0x7fc000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS:                     
      Size:                    8372224(0x7fc000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
    Pool 3                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: FINE GRAINED        
      Size:                    8372224(0x7fc000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
    Pool 4                   
      Segment:                 GROUP                              
      Size:                    64(0x40) KB                        
      Allocatable:             FALSE                              
      Alloc Granule:           0KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         0KB                                
      Accessible by all:       FALSE                              
  ISA Info:                
    ISA 1                    
      Name:                    amdgcn-amd-amdhsa--gfx900:xnack-   
      Machine Models:          HSA_MACHINE_MODEL_LARGE            
      Profiles:                HSA_PROFILE_BASE                   
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Fast f16:                TRUE                               
      Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
      Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        1024(0x400)                        
        y                        1024(0x400)                        
        z                        1024(0x400)                        
      Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      Grid Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      FBarrier Max Size:       32
```

Show video drivers

`~$ dpkg --list | grep amdgpu`

```
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                       2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1               amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  22.0.0-1ubuntu0.2                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

Any hints on what may go wrong?
Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. It is not relaited with a CPU because pop-up only in Ubuntu (last 545 driver). But Win10 never got any similar problems with Cuda or Torch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).